# Return value from a text file

Tags: c#, text

I want to return a value and overwrite from a text like: item_type=etcitem . I want to return value 'etcitem' by this code:

```
        var data = File
                    .ReadAllLines("itemdata.txt")
                    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

        textBox1.Text = data["item_type"];
```

But returns me error: the given key was not present in the dictionary.

Here Are some lines:

> item_begin    etcitem 6867    [rp_sealed_draconic_leather_gloves_i]   item_type=etcitem   slot_bit_type={none}    armor_type=none etcitem_type=recipe recipe_id=666   blessed=0   weight=0    default_action=action_recipe    consume_type=consume_type_stackable initial_count=1 maximum_count=1 soulshot_count=0    spiritshot_count=0

What I do wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What's the file data?

Comment: I bet you have spaces around your key value. Replace last clause with: `.ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

Comment: Show the data in the file.

Comment: where is the error? (what line)

Comment: Well obviously the `item_type` line isn't in the file or is not parsed properly.  I would run it in the debugger and see what your dictionary _does_ contain.

Comment: I used .Trim() too and same error. File looks lie this `item_type=etcitem slot_bit_type={none}` . Between item_type and slot_bit is TAB space.

Comment: @user2828891 Update your question to include a sample input file.

Comment: Loop all the keys and get the value for each of the keys. Log this information and you'll understand what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the value of `item_type` in the file?

Is every entry on a new line or are you using a different delimiter? From your example it looks like you need to split by tabs first.

```
var data = File
            .ReadAllLines("itemdata.txt")
            .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Try to view the the data in the debugger or in another `TextBox`.

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", data.Keys);
```

Also when the key isn't in the dictionary it might be helpful to tell the user using [`Dictionary(TKey, TValue).TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

```
string value;

textBox1.Text = data.TryGetValue("item_type", out value)
                ? value
                : "item_type not in file";
```

Comment: Is your data separated by line or by space?

Comment: textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", data.Keys); this returns me the line till item type weerd. the result now show.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a few lines from your file?

Comment: Done I did add some lines.

Comment: Are those spaces, tabs, or newlines?

Comment: Spaces. More exactly Tab Spaces.

Comment: Well you should split by `\t` first `ReadAllLines("itemdata.txt").SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t')).Select(x => x.Split('=')`.

Comment: Working very well. Tank you very much!

Comment: There is no code with `WriteAllLines`. If this is a separate issue then ask another question.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I have on this problem a question . How do I make read only from one line if textfile multiple lines with same value i search? Now it returns that: A item with the same key has already been added.